# Google Cloud IoT Core Device registration- can multiple devices use the same Public/Private Key

Tags: google-cloud-iot, spring-integration-mqtt

I am working on an in house project with several sensor devices. I do not want a user to register each and every device individually. In the sense I want to use the same Public/Private Key pair for all devices registering to a registry but be able to pass device information on to pubsub via mqtt/http with unique device information like name or id. Is it possible to achieve that?

I am assuming if i am using the same Keys. I am registering all devices as one but is it possible to send device info as part of the message being published. does doing that inhibit the usage of google's inbuilt functionality in any way like API's.

new to cloud technologies, any thoughts/suggestions would help.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on MQTT-broker configuration.

Normally Certificate based authorization is used only for authorisation on MQTT-Broker side. So you can use Public/Private Key pair to authorize and connect to the broker and use MQTT ClientID to differ between your devices.

MQTT-Broker can be also configured to use Identity from authorization Public/Private Key pair as Username.

```
use_identity_as_username true
```

In this case, if MQTT-Broker has also username based ACL configuration for example like that:

```
#device info sent from device. %u <- username
pattern readwrite %u/devinfo
```

All your devices will publish messages under same username, you should set different ClientID for each device or use CleanSession Flag in this case.

Here is a good reading to understand how the connection between device and broker works at all: https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-3-client-broker-connection-establishment/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you really want to be using the new gateway functionality (it's in beta now, but I've run through using it a bunch and it's quite stable).

Check out this tutorial on gateways to get an idea of what we're talking about:

https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-iot-gateways-rpi

TL;DR version is that it allows a single device to manage many smaller devices (which may not be capable of auth on their own) but still have those smaller devices be represented in the Cloud.

So basically, you have a more powerful device (like a Raspberry Pi, or a desktop machine, whatever) registered in IoT Core as a "Gateway". Then when you create the individual devices in the Cloud, you don't specify an SSL key (the Console will warn you about the device not being able to connect) and then you can "associate" the device with the gateway, and it'll handle the auth piece for you. Then the individual devices instead of calling out to the internet, connect and talk to the gateway device locally.